# Trying to create a random Vector3 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a random Vector3, but Unity is giving me this error: UnityException: Range is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehavior 'particleMover'.
This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;

public class particleMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float temperature;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform tf;
    static private float[] directions;

    // Start is called before the first frame
    void Start()
    {
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
        float[] directions = { rnd.Next(1, 360), rnd.Next(1, 360), rnd.Next(1, 360) };
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(directions[0], directions[1], directions[2]);
        direction = moveSpeed * direction;
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Vector3 direction = Random.insideUnitSphere;
```

And you used (1, 360) and it seems you are confusing direction with rotation.

Vector3(x, y, z) - x, y, z are position values, not angles.

In addition, you need to use `Time.deltaTime`

```
direction = moveSpeed * direction * Time.deltaTime;
```

More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html

Updated answer:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;

public class particleMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float temperature;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform tf;
    private Vector3 direction = Vector3.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        direction = Random.insideUnitSphere;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rf.position += direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        // If this script is attached to tf object
        // transform.position += direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I define at start and then use it in update? (Sorry if this is unrelated)

Comment: Vector3 direction = Vector3.zero;
  
  
void Start()
{
    direction = Random.insideUnitSphere;
}
  
  
void Update()
{
    rf.position += direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}

Comment: `direction = Random.insideUnitSphere` doesn't necessarily return a normalized direction vector. It is inside a unit sphere, not on its surface. So you should rather do `direction = Random.insideUnitSphere.normalized;`

Comment: agree with you. I just updated the answer 

Comment: the first part of the answer is **totally wrong**, @SatoshiNaoki . I have edited it out.  Feel free to edit as you wish.

Comment: also, note that it is incorrect to normalize a unit vector (which is normalized)

Comment: that's not totally wrong. only needed to use direction.normalized when use Random.Range(-1, 1)